# Displaying value in input field from sql database using jQuery

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql

I am still new to jQuery. I am trying to get the last id from a database and display it in a input field in a HTML form. When i inspect the browser i can see the value being retrieved from the database, however it is not displaying in the input field on the HTML form when i view the form, which i want it to display in the input field essentially.

Please see code below:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    {
        $('load_data').load("fetch.php");
    };
});
```

**HTML Form**

```
<form action="fetch.php" method="post">
   <label>Get Data From Database</label>
   <input type="text" value="" id="load_data"></input>
<button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**fetch.php file**

```
<?php
 
include('server.php');

$sql ="SELECT * FROM contents ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($res) >0)

{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))

    {
        echo $row["new_base"];
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: The purpose of `load` is to load HTML content, and then insert that into the current document afterwards. If you only want to get a single integer value, you should probably rather use `ajax` to begin with. Inside the callback function, you then simply use `$('#load_data').val(...)` to set the received value for the input field.

Comment: FYI: Using a _loop_ to iterate over the result set of a query that can return at most _one_ record, is a bit pointless.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe, i managed to sort it out using ajax. I posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this right using ajax as someone in the comments section suggested:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data_amount = $('#new_base').val();
       {
          $.ajax({
              url:"fetch.php",
              method:"POST",
              data:{new_base:data_amount},
              dataType:"text",
              contentType:false,
              processData:false,
              success:function(data:
              {
                $('#load_data').val(data);
              }
           });
       }
 });
```

Comment: Why is there still a `load` call in an interval, what is the purpose of that? Considering that you are still not even _doing anything_ with the content you are loading there, this seems rather pointless.

Comment: And `$('load_data')` won't select anything to begin with (there is no element with that _tag name_ in your document), so this probably doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: I removed that from the answer, only realized afterwards, it serves no function to what i have already achieved.